# Class Design for Python - Parameter Error

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, python-idle

I'm trying to create a python code for employees using the following code but it is coming up with an error "Object () takes no parameters)
My objective is to create a program to keep track of employees in an organisation, by allowing the user to add and remove employees from a simple database listing their staff names and number, salaries and update their salaries and read and write all the information into a text file.

So far this is my code:

```
class Employee:
    """ Employee has name, one staff number, number of years worked, Salary and Holiday"""

    def __init__(self, name, StaffNumber, YearsWorked, Salary, HolidayEntitlement):
        self._name=name
        self._StaffNumber=StaffNumber
        self._YearsWorked=[]
        self._Salary=[]
        self._HolidayEntitlement=[]


    def addEmployee(self) :
        text = int(input("Enter Employee's Name"))
        for i in range (text):
            self._name(input("Enter Employee's Name"))

e = Employee("Jean Green", "13026", "7", "£12,890", "42 days")

print ("Employee: ", e._name)
print ("Employee: ", e._StaffNumber)
print ("Employee: ", e._YearsWorked)
print ("Employee: ", e._Salary)
print ("Employee: ", e._HolidayEntitlement)
```

I'm not sure if my code is completely wrong.

Comment: You have to fix the indentation of your `__init__` method; other than that, your code works for me

Comment: fair warning: CamelCaps is usually reserved for class names in python, which makes your code a little weird to read (and is why the syntax highlighting is coloring all your attribute names).  you can just do `staff_number`, etc.

Comment: I dislike the CamelCap too.  Just to be clear, Idle (included in the tags but not relevant) does not color them.  In assignment statements, `=` should have spaces ` = ` for easier reading.

Comment: Added indent specified in answer by Etan.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is wrong. The `__init__` method is not indented properly under your class and so is being seen as a method outside the class. Which leaves your class with no methods and the default `__init__` function.

Push the indentation of that entire block of lines in by four spaces and your code will work.

Comment: sorry like how? so get rid of the ["__init__"]

Comment: No. Indent the code. Python is whitespace/indentation sensitive. Your `__init__` method is indented to the same level as your class definition which makes python think it isn't part of the class. Move it into the indentation level of the class (like your `addEmployee` method).

Comment: can you show me an example as im attempting and do not get it

Comment: Your `addEmployee` function **is** an example. It is indented correctly to be a part of the class. Just fix the indentation of the `__init__` function to match.

Comment: You even have the indentation right in the code you posted to your other question.

Comment: it doesn't function properly, it doesn't add what more or delete more employers

Comment: The fact that your code doesn't **work** is an entirely different issue. And there are a number of problems with the code itself. This question was about a specific error. The error the indentation caused. To figure out why your code isn't working as intended go look at it again. Where do you use the values you are passing to the `__init__` function? What does `addEmployee` actually do? (But those are all questions for a new question and not this one. Also questions not very well suited to this site.)

Comment: Ok, well do you think you will be able to help with with what I've done wrong I just want to understand the programm

Comment: Not on this question and as I said "help my code isn't working" isn't really an appropriate question for this site. One of the other network sites might be better or a non-network site geared towards teaching programming might be even better. I would also suggest that you just look at your code really carefully and try to think about what it is doing at each stage and where it is using/saving the values you are passing around.